# Xcode uses variable values of the same global array

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, c99

I work on a connect 4 game through Xcode (Mac). I scanned values into a global array (2 places) of the board's sizes and printed a game board with these sizes. after that part, the values inside the global array return to be {0,0}, as I initialized them, while they are supposed to remain the scanned values. I tried running the program through code blocks on windows and it does not have this problem. how can I fix it?

this is the initializing and printing the board sizes values part in the main:

```
#define BOARD_MAX_SIDE  25
int main()
{
int board_size[2]={0}, player1=1;
char board[BOARD_MAX_SIDE][BOARD_MAX_SIDE]={0}, color=0;
print_initial(board, board_size, color);
printf("SET: %d By %d\n", board_size[0], board_size[1]);
```

this is the print_initial function with the opening messages and the board printing:

```
void print_initial(char board[BOARD_MAX_SIDE][BOARD_MAX_SIDE], 
int board_size[], char color)
{
printf("got size: %d %d\n", board_size[0], board_size[1]);
printf("Welcome to 4-in-a-row game!");
do {
    printf("Please choose starting color (Y)ellow or (R)ed:");
    scanf("%s", &color);
} while (color!='R' && color!='Y');
do{
    printf("Please enter number of rows:");
    scanf("%d", board_size);
} while (board_size[0]<=0 || board_size[0]>25);
do{
    printf("Please enter number of columns:");
    scanf("%d", board_size+1);
} while (board_size[1]<=0 || board_size[1]>25);
print_board(board, board_size);
}
```

this is the function that prints the board:

```
#define IS_IN_RANGEI(VAL, MIN, MAX) (((VAL)>=(MIN)) && ((VAL)<=(MAX)))
enum {
    BOARD_VERT_SEP=(int)'|',
    BOARD_LEFT_ANG=(int)'\\',
    BOARD_RIGHT_ANG=(int)'/',
    BOARD_BOTTOM=(int)'-',
    BOARD_BOTTOM_SEP=(int)'-'
};
void print_board(char board[][BOARD_MAX_SIDE], int board_side[])
{
assert(IS_IN_RANGEI(board_side[0], 0, BOARD_MAX_SIDE)
   && IS_IN_RANGEI(board_side[1], 0, BOARD_MAX_SIDE));
for (int row=0; row<board_side[0]; ++row)
{
    printf("\n%c", (char)BOARD_VERT_SEP);
    for (int col = 0; col < board_side[1]; ++col)
        printf("%c%c", board[row][col], (char)BOARD_VERT_SEP);
}
printf("\n%c", (char)BOARD_LEFT_ANG);
for (int ii=0; ii<board_side[1]-1; ++ii)
    printf("%c%c", (char)BOARD_BOTTOM, (char)BOARD_BOTTOM_SEP);
printf("%c%c\n", (char)BOARD_BOTTOM, (char)BOARD_RIGHT_ANG);
}
```

and this is what the program prints:

```
Welcome to 4-in-a-row game! 
Please choose starting color (Y)ellow or (R)ed: R
Please enter number of rows: 5
Please enter number of columns: 4
|||||
|||||
|||||
|||||
|||||
\-------/
SET: 0 By 0
```

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've done a pretty good job on creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — well done!  (To finish it, I added `#include <assert.h>`, `#include <stdio.h>`, and declarations for the two functions before `int main(void)`, and `return 0; }` at the end of `main`.  There was then one unused variable (`player1` — my default compilation options make that into an error), but that was it.  Believe me, that is remarkably good.  However, when it was all compiled in a single file, using GCC 7.2.0, it worked correctly.  I had to make an extra tweak to placate `clang` in initializing the board.

Comment: That meant changing `= { 0 }` to `= { { 0 } }`.  It's fussy about that.  But with that, the code also worked .correctly.  That's on macOS 10.13.2, using `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`.  So, at the moment, I cannot reproduce the problem (the last printing is `SET: 5 By 4`).  What have you done differently from simply concatenating the three functions in a single file?  Something in what you've done is critically different from my code.  Shout if you want the code I'm exercising to test — an `@Jonathan` comment or see my profile.

Comment: I note that this is very closely related to your previous question [XCode does not initialize global array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877465/xcode-does-not-initialize-global-array-in-c).  I've not tracked through the code to see what's changed.  There's an accurate comment to that other question that you don't have a global array; you don't here, either.  Therefore, I'm not closing this as a duplicate, yet, but you need to explain what you've done differently, because the result shown is different.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `memset(board, sizeof(board), ' ');` in `main()` after the declaration of `board` and before the call to `print_initial()`?  You'd include `<string.h>` to get the declaration of that.  Using `= { 0 }` (or `= { { 0 } }` set the array to null bytes.  If you want them to be spaces, use an initialization such as the `memset()`.